# Protobuff package vs option csharp_namespace

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3, protocol-buffers-3

I am creating a gRPC service using Proto 3 and C#.

In the Google developer guide for Protobuff it says about `package`:

> In C# the package is used as the namespace after converting to PascalCase, unless you explicitly provide an option csharp_namespace in your .proto file.

So I'm not sure from that what's the difference between `package` and `option csharp_namespace`? What happens if I declare them both? If I declare one of them then is the other one redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are quite confusing in Protocol Buffers since people don't really see Protobuf as a language by itself. The protobuf `package` is useful for generation in your case (when you don't define `csharp_namespace`), but this is also useful within your proto files.

If you have:

#### a.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package my_package;

message A {}
```

in one file and you import this file in another which doesn't use the package, as so:

#### b.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "a.proto";

message B {
  my_package.A a = 1;
}
```

you will need to specify the fully qualified name (my_package.A).

Now, for `option csharp_namespace`. This will tweak the code generation and so that the namespace in your C# code is the one that you provided as value.
So, as for which one will prevail if you define both, it should be the option one since this is for tweaking the generation, where the `package` is more for you protobuf architecture.

Comment: In the example where you imported a.proto, what happens if b.proto does define a different package of its own? it sounds like it should remain the same? And what if the package is the same as in a.proto? Can I then use the messages from A inside B even without importing?

Comment: if you have different package, you will still have to use the fully qualified name (`my_package.A`). And if you define the same package, you still need to import but you can drop the `my_package.` part

Answer (score 0):

The package name will be used to give a name to the generated service, and this name will be used to generate the URL, which will be invoked during the call
to the remote procedure.
e.g.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package gRPCDemo.v1;
option csharp_namespace = "Branch.Sample.gRPC";
   service BranchService {
     rpc GetById (CountrySearchRequest) returns (CountryReply) {}
   }
```

so If a package name is not set, then the `__ServiceName` property will have the value of `BranchService`.